# Perturbation theory for triangular barrier

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory, ground-state

My teacher asked us to use perturbation theory to get the energy of the ground state in such potential:
$$
V = \left \{ 
\begin{aligned}
\infty \quad x < 0 \\
Ax \quad x \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\right .
$$
I don’t know how to use the perturbation theory, although I know how to get the precise solution.

Comment: What Hamiltonian is being perturbed?  To use perturbation theory, you have to a Hamiltonian that looks like $\hat{H}= \hat{H}_0 +\hat{V}$, where $\hat{V}$ is the perturbation.  What is $\hat{H}_0$?

Comment: Hmm, since you are after a bound state and you don't have bound states for $A = 0$, I don't see how standard perturbation theory for small $A$ would work (which computes energy corrections for discrete states). The second problem I see is that the perturbation is not small for large $x$. You could make this into a standard perturbation theory problem by adding a second wall to the well (but I don't immediately see how you can extrapolate to the case of no second wall from this, as this wall has to be at a distance where $Ax$ is still small).

Was any hint given how to attack the problem?

Comment: @march Well, I’m also confused by this question. In fact, I think our teacher want us to construct the $\hat{H}_0$ and $\hat{V}’$?

Comment: Is there an assumption that this is supposed to be in an infinite square well or something? Otherwise, there's not way to figure that out just from $\hat{V}$. I suppose the unperturbed system could just be the one that has a hard wall on at 0 and is flat out to infinity, but then you wouldn't be able to do perturbation theory because there are no bound states for that system.

Comment: @SebastianRiese Thanks for your comments, I don’t know how can I extrapolate to the case of no second wall, too…

Comment: @march Yeah… but out teacher said that there is no infinite square well and there is no problem with this potential.

Comment: You sure it's *perturbation* theory and not a *variational* calculation?  Otherwise, I'm at a loss.

Comment: I suspect there is either a typo or miscommunication somewhere. If you insist on using perturbation theory, you could just pick some $H_0$ with bound states, then let $H=H_0 +(V-H_0)$ so that the perturbation is $V-H_0$

Comment: @march … or *WKB*…